# Filestream feature is disabled while recreating the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfilestream

While I recreate a MS SQL Server database it gives me the following error. 
"Filestream feature is disabled."
I really need that feature and it was previously enabled on the existing copy if the database but since I am trying to recreate it how is it possible to enable a feature on a database that is still not created?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it enabled on the server?

Comment: Yes, it is, @M.Ali

Comment: Have you restarted sql server since you have enabled it? And what do you mean by `Recreate Database`? what is it exactly that you are doing?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx check the **13 step** it says *Restart the SQL Server service*

Comment: Yes, the service has been restarted several times and by recreating the database I mean restoring from a .mdf file with a different name due to test cases.  @M.Ali

Comment: Some interesting facts are: 
- When I check the Filestream service status on the server node in SQL managment studio it says "Full Access Enabled"; 
- When I open SQL Server Coffiguration Manager and click the SQL Server Services it says "The Remote Procedure call failed" (i'm not sure if this issue is related to the case) @M.Ali